# Simplifying a SpatialPointsDataFrame in ggplot world

Tags: r, sp, mapping, ggplot2

I've been working on a map showing lines running across Europe. Each line is coming from a GPX file, parsed in like so:

```
spdf <- readOGR("data/file.gpx", layer = "track_points")
```

Now, if I plot the map using `plot()`, I can simplify each of these lines without any issue:

```
spdf_simple <- gSimplify(spdf, tol = 0.1)
```

However, in this particular instance I am using `ggplot2` and need to keep a dataframe structure, as I'm doing some filtering (see below):

```
# load each file
for (file in list.files('data/') {
    # parse each file
    track_points <- readOGR(paste("data/", file, sep = ""), layer = "track_points")
    track_points@data$time_clean <- ymd_hms(track_points@data$time)

    # we need to preserve @data to filter the time value later on
    df1 <- data.frame(track_points@data)
    df2 <- data.frame(track_points@coords)
    df <- bind_cols(df1, df2)

    # filter out all records that happened after FINISH time
    df.filter <- df %>%
      filter(time_clean < FINISH) %>% 
      select(time, coords.x1, coords.x2) %>%
      mutate(group = file)
    colnames(df.filter) <- c('time', 'lon', 'lat', 'group')

    paths <- rbind(paths, df.filter)
}
```

Subsequently I can plot my paths like so:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_path(data = paths, aes(lon, lat, group = group))
```

Now the result of `gSimplify` is a `sp::SpatialPoints` object which doesn't preserve what's in `@data`.

I'd like to simplify these paths, although I'm at a loss as to where to do it in ggplot world.

Comment: If I read a GPX with `layer="track_points"` and then plot it with `plot(spdf)` I gt points, not a track. Then running `gSimplify` on points doesn't actually do any simplification - it returns the points without the attributes. Maybe you need to read the `tracks` layer?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do this using the `sf` package.

First read in the GPS track points and I'll assign some time points to each point because my demo GPX doesn't have time stamps:

```
> library(sf)
> pts = st_read("./uni2track.gpx","track_points", quiet=TRUE)
> dim(pts)
[1] 13 27
> pts$time = Sys.time() + (1:nrow(pts)*73)
> pts$time
 [1] "2018-11-18 17:21:28 GMT" "2018-11-18 17:22:41 GMT"
 [3] "2018-11-18 17:23:54 GMT" "2018-11-18 17:25:07 GMT"
 [5] "2018-11-18 17:26:20 GMT"  (etc, 13 time points)
```

If I do `plot(pts)` I see points, not a track. To make a track, I need to combine the points to multipoint, and then cast that to a LINESTRING:

```
> track = st_cast(st_combine(pts),"LINESTRING")
> track
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -2.788547 ymin: 54.0087 xmax: -2.784867 ymax: 54.01289
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
LINESTRING (-2.785507 54.00952, -2.785587 54.01...
```

Now that's a single row (feature) representing a track. Plotting it shows a line. The attributes at each point are gone, but don't worry we'll get them back shortly.

Now we simplify the LINESTRING track feature:

```
> track_simple = st_simplify(track, dTolerance=0.001)
```

`track_simple` now has five points. To find out which points they are in the original data, use `st_intersection`:

```
> track_simple_pts = st_intersection(pts, track_simple)
```

And then I can get the attributes at each point in `track_simple` as:

```
> track_simple_pts$time
[1] "2018-11-18 17:21:28 GMT" "2018-11-18 17:26:20 GMT"
[3] "2018-11-18 17:31:12 GMT" "2018-11-18 17:34:51 GMT"
[5] "2018-11-18 17:36:04 GMT"
>
```